# I want to return the following json response format

Tags: arrays, json, laravel, laravel-8, prepared-statement

How do I return the following response format using the code below:

```
{"data":[],"meta":{"paging":{"links":[],"total":0},"time":0.079}}
```

**The controller code:**

```
public function someMethod()
    {
        $var=SomeModel::with(['status' => function ($query) {
            $query->where('name', 'like', '%Pending Payment%');
        }])->get();

        return [
            'data' => $var,
        ];


    }
```

**Response am getting**

```
{"data":[]}
```

Comment: $var is not returning anything so its empty...

Comment: @KGG even the first case its empty but its returning empty data if you keenly observe it.Kindly check it out.My interest is on the second object "meta":{"paging":{"links":[],"total":0},"time":0.079}

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using Resource Collection

```
public function toArray($request)
        {
            return [
                'data' => $this->collection,
                'meta' => [
                    'paging' => [
                        'links'=>[],
                         'total'=>0,
                    ],
                ],
                'time'=>'',
    
            ];
    
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$data = Order::query();

        // Apply filters and/or sorting to the data query
        // ...

        $paginator = $data->paginate(5);

        $paginatedData = [
            'data' => $paginator->items(),
            'meta' => [
                'paging' => [
                    'links' => $paginator->links(),
                    'total' => $paginator->total(),
                ],
                'time' => microtime(true) - LARAVEL_START,
            ],
        ];

        return response()->json($paginatedData);
```